inject() must be called from an injection context after upgrading Angular from v14 to v17
I've recently updated my Angular project from v14 to v17. After doing so, I have received many injection errors when running my project / test code.
I am using Angular 17.3.2, Node 20.11.1, Typescript 5.4.3 and NX 18.2.3.
I am aware that as of v16, I should be using runInInjectionContext, but I feel as if I'm not understanding where all it should be used from the documentation. Do I have to add that everywhere that a service is used? And does it need to be added in services AND components?
The exact error stack when running my project:
main.ts:14  Error: NG0203: inject() must be called from an injection context such as a constructor, a factory function, a field initializer, or a function used with `runInInjectionContext`. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0203
    at injectInjectorOnly (core.mjs:1093:15)
    at Module.ɵɵinject (core.mjs:1106:60)
    at Object.RouterModule_Factory [as useFactory] (router.mjs:424:103)
    at Object.factory (core.mjs:3322:38)
    at core.mjs:3219:47
    at runInInjectorProfilerContext (core.mjs:866:9)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (core.mjs:3218:21)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:3082:33)
    at injectInjectorOnly (core.mjs:1100:40)
    at ɵɵinject (core.mjs:1106:60)

The exact function that is throwing the error in core.mjs:1093:
function injectInjectorOnly(token, flags = InjectFlags.Default) {
    if (_currentInjector === undefined) {
        throw new RuntimeError(-203 /* RuntimeErrorCode.MISSING_INJECTION_CONTEXT */, ngDevMode &&
            `inject() must be called from an injection context such as a constructor, a factory function, a field initializer, or a function used with \`runInInjectionContext\`.`);
    }
    else if (_currentInjector === null) {
        return injectRootLimpMode(token, undefined, flags);
    }
    else {
        const value = _currentInjector.get(token, flags & InjectFlags.Optional ? null : undefined, flags);
        ngDevMode && emitInjectEvent(token, value, flags);
        return value;
    }
}

Error happens in my main.ts at platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule):
platformBrowserDynamic()
    .bootstrapModule(AppModule)
    .then(platformRef => {
        let injector = platformRef.injector;
        runInInjectionContext(injector, () => {
            let notificationService = inject(NotificationService);
            let authService = inject(AuthService);
            let coBrandingService = inject(CoBrandingService);
            let coreCacheService = inject(CoreCacheService);
            let eventService = inject(EventService);
            let loginService = inject(LoginService);
            authService.RegisterHook(notificationService);
            authService.RegisterHook(coBrandingService);
            authService.RegisterHook(coreCacheService);
            authService.RegisterHook(eventService);
            authService.RegisterHook(loginService);
        });
    });

Component usage I have tried, but not yet commited to adding everywhere:
export class MyComponent{
   constructor(private service1: FirstService, private service2: SecondService, private injector: EnvironmentInjector) {}

   ngOnInit() {
       runInInjectionContext(this.injector, () => {
           inject(FirstService);
           inject(SecondService);
       })
   }
}

Service usage I have tried, but not yet commited to adding everywhere:
@Injectable()
export class MyService{
   constructor(private service2: SecondService, private injector: EnvironmentInjector) {}

   ServiceMethod() {
       runInInjectionContext(this.injector, () => {
           let result = this.service2.SecondServiceMethod();
           return result;
       })
   }
}

I have also tried adding @angular/* to compilerOptions.paths as shown here
And I have tried setting build.options.preserveSymlinks to true as discussed here
I have ensured that the module I am attempting to bootstrap is providing the services that should be available in the InjectionEnvironment:
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        NotificationService,
        AuthService,
        CoBrandingService,
        CoreCacheService,
        EventService,
        LoginService,
        { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' }
        // ... Others removed for brevity ...
    ],
    bootstrap: [
        AppComponent
    ]
})
export class AppModule { }


Please share the original code that was giving you injection errors, from what I can see there is no need for inject or runInInjectionContext

Updated question with this information. It is erroring in my main.ts file when my project is first loading

could you share the full stack trace for this error, if possible place a breakpoint in chrome debugger at core.mjs:1093 and observe the stacktrace on the right side bottom, there you will find the exact line that gives you the problem, maybe you are using inject somewhere in your application

Updated question with the core.mjs function that is causing the issue. Seems that my injector is undefined. Should I be creating this somewhere using something similar to this or should that be done automatically during bootstrapModule() / bootstrapApplication()

I had the same issue after upgrading to v17 and switching to the new "application" builder (even if I removed all my components and left a clean project).
After hours of debugging and comparing my project to a freshly created one, I have finally found the case.
In my tsconfig.json I had compilerOptions > paths with:
"@angular/*" : [
    "./node_modules/@angular/*"
]

and exactly this entry was causing the error. It's no longer necessary (or never was?), as you can use imports from @angular/whatever without explicitly specifying this path alias in the tsconfig.json.

Holy Jeebus, you just redeemed 2 days of debugging hell. Thank you!
Interestingly, in my case the issue arose when upgrading from Angular 17 to 18.

FYI, removing this path reference from tsconfig.ts caused a secondary issue that vscode editors would not recognize exports from @angular modules. This caused a lot of red squiggly lines in the editor, even though Angular could build the project fine.
This solution for setting the TypeScript version cleared things up for me.

Yes this solved a huge pain for me too, upgrading from 14 to 18. Very confusing error message and took me a while to find this awesome answer!

Thanks so much, I was doing update to Angular 17 and I had the same issue.

You are almost there. The only thing missing is injector.get(MyService) should be replaced by inject(MyService) inside the runInInjectionContext callback.
import { inject, runInInjectionContext } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
import { UserService } from './app/admin/user.service';

platformBrowserDynamic()
  .bootstrapModule(AppModule).then((platform)=> {
    const injector = platform.injector
    const result = runInInjectionContext(injector, () => {
      const service = inject(UserService);
      return service.doSomething();
    })
  })
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));

Sidenote:
I don't think that you have to do custom injection in the components or device files.
Angular's default dependency injection will do that for you.
just do constructor(private userService: UserService) in the component and from there use it.

David, thanks for the quick and informative response! I gave this an attempt and updated my main.ts files to contain inject() and runInInjectionContext() but am still getting the same error. I updated the question with more information on where this is failing, but I think I just need to figure out why the injector is still null during the bootstrapModule line. Is this related to Ivy as said here? or are there some settings that need added to the @Injectable() decorator?

After much headache, I figured out what the issue was for me. I was importing a library that we build ourselves, and that library had a different version for the @angular packages than the root project since we upgraded them both a few weeks apart. After ensuring the packages the two projects shared under were the same version (did so for non-angular packages as well), this error went away for me. When they were different versions, they didn't share the same context anymore, disallowing for proper injection.
